# Plotting timeline in dash or bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, timeline, plotly-dash

I want to plot a timeline in `python`. but accuse matplotlib have problem with Arabic words i want to use `dash` or `bokeh` for this.
I searched the internet but can't find anything to plot timeline in those.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Bokeh, you can find a simple example on [this](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#datetime-axes) page.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL

df = pd.DataFrame(AAPL)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

output_file("datetime.html")

# create a new plot with a datetime axis type
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")

p.line(df['date'], df['close'], color='navy', alpha=0.5)

show(p)
```